# Can I suppress the Restart request message when pushing a WAP provisioning update to a Windows Mobile device?

Tags: configuration, windows-mobile

Our automatic maintenance procedure sends out provisioning updates like this to our devices overnight:

```
<wap-provisioningdoc>
    <characteristic type="SoftwareDisable">
        <characteristic type="DisabledSystemFiles">
            <parm name="Labyrinth.exe" />
        </characteristic>
    </characteristic>
</wap-provisioningdoc>
```

This works fine, apart from it pops up a box asking the user if they want to restart now or later, specifically:

```
Restart

Recent changes to your device require a 
restart. During this process you cannot make 
or receive phone calls, including emergency 
calls. Restart your device now? 

Now                             Later
```

This is of course difficult to do because there is no user, just racks and racks of devices sitting there by themselves.

So, is there any way of not popping this message up and just restarting the device automatically? Possibly some registry setting or something?

Answer (score 1):

You can soft reset your device via code.

Just need to p/invoke

```
  public enum SystemPowerStates : uint
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// On state.
        /// </summary>
        On = 0x00010000,

        /// <summary>
        /// No power, full off.
        /// </summary>
        Off = 0x00020000,

        /// <summary>
        /// Critical off.
        /// </summary>
        Critical = 0x00040000,

        /// <summary>
        /// Boot state.
        /// </summary>
        Boot = 0x00080000,

        /// <summary>
        /// Idle state.
        /// </summary>
        Idle = 0x00100000,

        /// <summary>
        /// Suspend state.
        /// </summary>
        Suspend = 0x00200000,

        /// <summary>
        /// Reset state.
        /// </summary>
        Reset = 0x00800000
    }

    [DllImport("coredll.dll")]
    internal static extern int SetSystemPowerState(string psState, int StateFlags, int Options);



    /// <summary>
    /// Defines the System power requirement flags
    /// </summary>
    public enum PowerReqFlags : uint
    {
        POWER_NAME = 0x00000001,
        POWER_FORCE = 0x00001000,
    }
```

And call the function SetSystemPowerState, I use it enclosed in another method.

```
 private static void DeviceReset()
    {
        SetSystemPowerState(
                            null,
                            (int)SystemPowerStates.Reset,
                         (int)PowerReqFlags.POWER_FORCE);
    }
```

Comment: I could also use `ExitWindowsEx(EWX_REBOOT, SHTDN_REASON_MINOR_MAINTENANCE | SHTDN_REASON_FLAG_PLANNED)` for a programmatic shutdown.   I was hoping for something I could send in a provisioniong message to make the shutdown smoother, rather than having to run a separate process.